# connect to restful api using Jquery to stream video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I create Restfull Api to stream video .mp4 format it ran as I want.after that I add drop down list had videos list in dir.when the user select video it will stream it i did that using jquery but I have problem when I want to make selected video to play. it give me 404 found

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="ddlcas"></select>
    <br />
    <video id="mainPlayer" width="1280" height="720"
           autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" onloadeddata="onLoad()">
        <source src="" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(function () {

    //variables 
    var selectedFile = "";

    ////load data into table to view all car 
    $("#ddlcas").load(GetFiles());


    function GetFiles() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/media/GetFiles',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var appenddata;
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    appenddata += "<option value = '" + value + " '>" + value + " </option>";
                });
                $('#ddlcas').html(appenddata);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#ddlcas").change(function () {

        selectedFile = $('#ddlcas').val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        $("source").load(Paly(selectedFile));

    });


    function Paly(src)
    {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/media/play?f=' + selectedFile,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('source').attr('src', data);;
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$("#ddlcas").load(GetFiles());


function GetFiles() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/media/GetFiles',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var appenddata;
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                appenddata += "<option value = '" + value + " '>" + value + " </option>";
            });
            $('#ddlcas').html(appenddata);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
}

$("#ddlcas").change(function () {

    var selectedFile = $('#ddlcas').val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    $('#mainPlayer source').attr('src', 'api/media/play?f=' + selectedFile);;
    $('#mainPlayer')[0].load();
});
```